# How to display all nodes and relationships' names in sequence from a Neo4j path

Tags: neo4j, path, cypher

I would like to know how to display the names of every node and relationship generated from a path p in Neo4j Cypher.

I have this query:

```
MATCH (m { name: 'porsche' }),(n { name: 'vehicle' }), p =(m)-[r*]->(n) 
return collect(p);
 ══════════════════════════════╕
│"collect(p)"                  │
╞══════════════════════════════╡
│[[{"name":"porsche"},{"name":"│
│is a"},{"name":"car","type":"l│
│abel"},{"name":"car","type":"l│
│abel"},{"name":"is a subtype o│
│f"},{"name":"vehicle","type":"│
│label"}],[{"name":"porsche"},{│
│"name":"is a"},{"name":"car","│
│type":"label"},{"name":"car","│
│type":"label"},{},{"name":"veh│
│icle","type":"label"}]]       │
└──────────────────────────────┘
```

But I want it do display each node's name and then each Relationship's name in sequence like this:

```
'porsche' 'is a' 'car'
'car' 'is a subtype of' vehicle
```

Comment: Please share with us the Cypher query to create a initial data set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*The output shown in your question indicates that your data is not well formed. For example, not all relationships actually have a `name`. This answer assumes well-formed data, but can be tweaked to handle missing `name` properties if needed.*

Since your question was not clear about what you wanted, here are some options.

#### Option 1

This query will return a name triplet (in a list) for each relationship of each path:

```
MATCH ({ name: 'porsche' })-[rels*]->({ name: 'vehicle' })
WITH [r IN rels | [STARTNODE(r).name, r.name, ENDNODE(r).name]] AS steps
UNWIND steps AS step
RETURN step;
```

Sample output (for one path):

```
["porsche", "is a", "car"]
["car", "is a subtype of", "vehicle"]
```

#### Option 2

If you want to keep apart the results for each path, you can replace `UNWIND path_names AS names RETURN names;` with `RETURN path_names;`. That would produce somehting like this for each path:

```
[["porsche", "is a", "car"], ["car", "is a subtype of", "vehicle"]]
```

#### Option 3

If you want to get the distinct "steps" from all paths, you can do this:

```
MATCH ({ name: 'porsche' })-[rels*]->({ name: 'vehicle' })
WITH [r IN rels | [STARTNODE(r).name, r.name, ENDNODE(r).name]] AS steps
UNWIND steps AS step
RETURN DISTINCT step;
```

The result will look like the result for Option 1, except each "step" will be distinct.

Comment: Very nice answer! Thank you

Comment: I want to know, how do I get an output like this to only touch each node/relationship ONCE: ["porsche", "is a", "car", "is a subtype of", "vehicle"].  I don't want the lists to be separated, but be just as they were traversed in the using path=.  Can you use path= and solve the same problem?  Thanks again!

Comment: Hey, Thanks again!

Comment: I was wondering, how do I get an output totally as a string like this: "porsche is a car", "car is a subtype of vehicle".  Even furthermore, how could I append and detect redundancies and replace them to get an output like this: "porsche is a car, which is a subtype of vehicle".  I would be grateful

Comment: That should be possible, but then the "steps" cannot be distinct, since a step could appear in multiple generated sentences. But, I'll work on it.